# how to fix USBASP Unknown USB Device (device descriptor request failed) - Win 10?

Tags: serial, avr, avrdude, usbasp

I just recently purchased Usbasp from Ali Express, when i'm connecting it to the windows 10 desktop in device manager its Unknown USB Device (device descriptor request failed). How to fix this error? Even in Linux its not detecting.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a dud. Contact the seller and get a replacement or refund.

Comment: @Majenko I just pick my rework station hotair gun to destroy this board and melt all the solder on the board, then i plugged it in for last time and its stated working but now i'm getting this error https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/usbasp-arduino-uno-bootloader-flash-error-win-10