# Usbasp Arduino Uno Bootloader Flash Error - Win 10

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, flash, usbasp

I'm trying to flash an Arduino Uno using usbasp but i'm getting the following error,I have checked all the connection and voltage using multimeter but still this error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\SillyMonster\Desktop\arduino-1.8.8\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\SillyMonster\Desktop\arduino-1.8.8\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cusbasp -Pusb -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\SillyMonster\Desktop\arduino-1.8.8\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbasp
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : usbasp
         Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

**I have tried different three other `Usbasp` but still same error**

[image: Different USPasp]

Comment: This is the same dead programmer from before? Check the traces and connections on the programmer for shorts / open circuits. Also the cable.

Comment: @Majenko It's the dead programmer form before. I am using desktop with Intel Coffee Lake processor and MSI Z370 motherboard, can this cause any problem?

Comment: Take it out of the lake of coffee? Your computer is irrelevant. The fact that you have a known dead programmer is all that matters.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks

Comment: @Majenko i just need to flash the boot loader on an arduino uno, this time i'm using Arduino as ISP and getting this https://pastebin.com/3FhQfA6R, Connection: [IMG1](https://ibb.co/1nVGnSD)  [IMG2](https://ibb.co/n6bvYdq)

Comment: I have tried two different arduinos as isp but same error.

Comment: You have nothing to prevent the Nano resetting when avrdude opens the serial port...?

Comment: What i have to do to use the arduino nano to burn the boot-loader on the UNO?

Comment: Stop it from resetting. Have you read any of the (good) tutorials?

Comment: Can you share me a link of good tutorial to understand fully?

Comment: https://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/use-arduino-as-an-isp-programmer-to-program-non-arduino-avr-microcontrollers

Comment: @Majenko I have tried different three other Usbasp but still same error

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the Arduinos i have received from AliExpress All of them are using WAVGAT AVGA 328P-AU chips. I flasthed other Atmel MEGA 328P chip based Arduinos using USbasp and it's working fine. But i dont know how to flash those WAVGAT AVGA 328P-AU chips.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Those clone chips cannot be flashed over the ISP port. So you cannot change the bootloader at all. Just a piece of junk in my opinion.