# Arduino UNO R3 clone acting as Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, avrdude

I just got a bunch of Arduino Uno R3 (ATmega328P + CH340).In arduino IDE when i'm selecting board as Arduino UNO then i'am getting this error

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM7
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf
```

**But, When i'm selecting Arduino Nano it's working fine. How to fix it?**

Comment: why do you feel that something needs to be fixed? .... are you having problems compiling sketches? .... upvote for investigating and finding a workaround

Comment: burn the Uno bootloader

Comment: @jsotola https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/usbasp-arduino-uno-bootloader-flash-error-win-10

Comment: @Juraj  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/usbasp-arduino-uno-bootloader-flash-error-win-10

Comment: @Juraj i have selected  target board type in Tools menu, on linux arvdude cli i'am getting same error

Comment: @Juraj I received the UNO with Nano Bootloader so i am trying to flashing it